Какие документации можете посоветовать для изучения Node.js?
Дело в том, что я просмотрел множество документаций для изучения Node.js, но все они либо устаревшие, либо не понятные. Node.js мне нужен для создания бота в дискорд, но где его учить я не понимаю. Если вы знаете хорошие документации или какие-то онлайн-учебники, буду рад, если подскажете!

Источник:
Создаем Discord-бота с помощью Node.js
